# Add ScriptReference dynamically, when declared in global.asax

Tags: asp.net

I can use `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).Scripts.Add(New ScriptReference("<path to javascript file>"))` perfectly well for references that are only applicable on a select few pages, however all my other ScriptRespourceMapping's are defined in `global.asax`.

Is there a way to refer to the ScriptReference through the ScriptResourceMapping?

Should avoid some duplication.. thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by using [ScriptManager.RegisterNamedClientScriptResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registernamedclientscriptresource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)